# Apache Workbook Write Issue: writes in two files?

Tags: excel, apache, save

What is the default way to save a workbook in the same file and in another file? Using Apache POI

I open the workbook

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(sourceFile);
```

do some changes and try to save it in another file:

```
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath().replace(".xls", "Mod.xls")));
```

Curiously sourceFile.xsl and SourceFileMod.xls are saved !

Comment: If really `sourceFile` is also changed then this can not be caused by the two lines code you are showing.

Comment: When I remove the workbook.write... line both files are saved. If I restore the line two files (original and ..Mod.xlsx) are updated (content changed and timestamp)

Comment: As I said this is *not* caused by the code you have shown. There must be other code around who causes this.

Comment: @AxelRichter ok my mistake - but the workbook seems to be saved at the next line: `workbook.close`. How do I close it without saving?